# Schematron rule to check if files have corresponding elements

Tags: xslt, schematron

I have a file structure like this:

```
bookmap.ditamap
├── en-US/
│   └── CTR_MyProduct.ditamap
├── es-ES/
│   └── CTR_MyProduct.ditamap
└── fr-FR/
    └── CTR_MyProduct.ditamap
```

The content of **bookmap.ditamap** is:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE bookmap PUBLIC "-//OASIS//DTD DITA BookMap//EN" "bookmap.dtd">
<bookmap>
    <booktitle><mainbooktitle/></booktitle>
    <part>
        <mapref href="en-US/CTR_Product.ditamap"/>
    </part>
    <part>
        <mapref href="fr-FR/CTR_Product.ditamap"/>
    </part>
</bookmap>
```

I'd like to have a **Schematron** rule which should crawl through the subdirectories looking for files starting with `CTR_` and ending with `.ditamap` which complains if there is no corresponding `<part>` element, like:

```xml
<part>
  <mapref href="xx-YY/CTR_Product.ditamap"/>
</part>
```

In this example, there is no `<part>` element for the Spanish (`es-ES`) map. This should be reported. Do you think this is possible to validate in **Schematron**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With underlying XSLT/XPath 3 support and Saxon 9 or 10 or 11 you can probably do e.g.

```
every $uri in uri-collection('?select=CTR_Product.ditamap;recurse=yes') 
satisfies 
  some $part in part 
  satisfies contains($uri, $part/mapref/@href)
```

If those elements are in a namespace you will need to set that up too as the default XPath selection namespace.

You can also use wildcards e.g. `uri-collection('?select=CTR_*.ditamap;recurse=yes')`.

Perhaps using `ends-with($uri, $part/mapref/@href)` instead of `contains($uri, $part/mapref/@href)` is a better way to check.

More complete in the context of Schematron:

```
    <sch:rule context="bookmap">
        <sch:let name="parts" value="part"/>
        <sch:let name="uris" value="uri-collection('?select=*.ditamap;recurse=yes')"/>
        <sch:assert test="every $uri in $uris
            satisfies 
            some $part in part 
            satisfies ends-with($uri, $part/mapref/@href)">
            Not every URI exists. 
            <sch:value-of select="$uris[not(some $ref in $parts/mapref satisfies ends-with(., $ref/@href))]"/>
        </sch:assert>  
    </sch:rule>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this is very impressive.